# How to group records by a child document field in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Assuming we have following data

*** Parent ***

```
{ _id: 10, child: ObjectID(20) }
{ _id: 11, child: ObjectID(21) }
{ _id: 12, child: ObjectID(23) }
```

*** Children ***

```
{ _id: 20, name: 'test-1' }
{ _id: 21, name: 'test-2' }
{ _id: 22, name: 'test-3' }
{ _id: 23, name: 'test-1' }
```

I would like know what mongoose to use to get following result.

```
{ _id: 'test-1', count: 2}
{ _id: 'test-2', count: 1}
```

I am currently using following query, but the _id in the result is always `{ _id: null, count: 3 }`
:(

```
Parent.aggregate([{
  $group: {
     _id: '$child.name',
     count: { $sum: 1 }
  }
}])
```

Any form of help is appreciated.

Comment: these are two different collections ?

Comment: yes they are different collections @Yogesh

Comment: In this case you should write two different query first on parent collections get all child ids and used that child ids in children collection using `$in` in aggregation `$match` and group by `name` and finally `sum`

Comment: @Yogesh could you elaborate in the answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better way to create one single collections for avoiding two query on two different collections.

First you should find out all distinct child ids from parent collections and assign to it variable as below :

```
var allChildIds = db.parent.distinct("child")
```

After that used that child ids in `children` collection as below :

```
db.children.aggregate({"$match":{"_id":{"$in":allChildIds}}},{"$group":{"_id":"$name","sum":{"$sum":1}}})
```